# Using Grasp Controller with MVC Controller - How to make an object always visible for a Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

UML and Patterns: An Introduction to Object-Oriented Analysis and Design and Iterative Development, that follows the UP(Unified Process). It uses a Grasp Controller pattern to interact with domain classes by some methods like NewSale(), AddNewItemToSale() and CloseSale. In windows form, I can instantiate a object of this class in the UI and then use its methods to perform the actions. This works well in Client apps, but when I use asp.net mvc, I cannot find a way to instantiate an object (one for each user) that was always visible for a Controller (MVC). I cannot insert as an attribute inside Controller because it always create a new one. Is there any way to work like that in the MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Use session variable to store the value and extend you controller class and add a custom property to return the type. This way the object will be available in post back through that custom property

```
Public DBContext Context 
{
get { 
if(Session["DBContext"] == null)
    Session["DBContext"] = New Context();

return Session["DBContext"]  as DBContext;
}
```